# How to plot parametric phase diagram with bar legend?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, legending, parametric-functions

I am trying to plot the parametric phase diagram with bar legend in the form of a rainbow. I have asked one similar question before in which I have shown the region plot. But equations are different there. Here I have simplified the equations.
I have written this code for getting the plot but not showing any color phase diagram as I want. If anyone can resolve this it will be appreciated.

```
k1 = 0.1;
kexc = .2;
ome = .4;
kL = (k1 + kexc)/2 - del0*(k1 - kexc)/(2*ome);
g0 = 0.3;
ome1 = 5.5;
a1 = 0.1;
A1 = 1;
B1 = 0;
gma = 0.0001;
delta = -1.5;
Y1 = (k1 - kexc)*g0^2*B1*ome1*(1 - del0/ome)*A1;
M1 = (gma^2/4 + ome1^2);
X1 = kL/2 + (k1 - kexc)/(ome^2*Sqrt[2]*M1)*g0^2*B1^2*ome1*P0*a1;
Z1 = delta + g0^2*(1 - del0/ome)*A1/Sqrt[2]*ome1/ome*P0*B1*a1/M1;
K1 = g0^2/2 (1 - del0/ome)^2*A1^2*ome1/M1;
S1 = g0^2/(2*Sqrt[2]*ome)*B1*ome1*(1 - del0/ome)*A1/M1;
O1 = (1 - del0/(2*ome))/Sqrt[2] + P0*g0^2*B1^2*ome1*a1/(2*ome^2*M1);
F11 = NSolve[
  r1^3*(Y1^2 + K1^2) + r1^2*(2*X1*Y1 + 2*Z1*K1) + 
    r1*(X1^2 + Z1^2 + P0^2*S1 + 2*P0^2*O1*S1) + P0^2*O1 == 0, r1]
CounterPlot[{r1}, {P0, 0, 2.5}, {del0, 0, 3}, 
 BarLegend["Rainbow", {0, 6}]]
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do in this code, but I can tell that you're using `NSolve` and `ContourPlot` incorrectly.  (1) `NSolve` generates a list of rules that need to be applied to `r1`;  replace `r1` with `r1 /. F11` if you want to plot the solutions to the functions found by `NSolve`.  (2)  The syntax for a legend is `PlotLegends->`(something).  (3)  You misspelled `ContourPlot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's `ContourPlot`, not `CounterPlot`.
2. If you fix that, your code will then complain about `BarLegend`.
3. If you remove `BarLegend`, it will return nothing, because `r1` does not have a value. You have not substituted the solutions of your equation in it...

You also receive three solutions to your equation. I do not know the physical significance, but you may have to choose the right one or treat them one at a time. That's up to you. I do not know your model of physical problem.

First, rationalize numbers rather than use machine-precisions:

```
k1 = 1/10;
kexc = 2/10;
ome = 4/10;
kL = (k1 + kexc)/2 - del0*(k1 - kexc)/(2*ome);
g0 = 3/10;
ome1 = 55/10;
a1 = 1/10;
A1 = 1;
B1 = 0;
gma = 1/10000;
delta = -3/2;
```

Use the rest of your definitions as is, except for `F11`, where I will use `Solve` instead of `NSolve`, and ask specifically for `Real` solutions only, so Solve will generate `ConditionalExpression` results that include appropriate conditions on the parameters that make the expressions reals (your original code could generate imaginary results):

```
F11 = 
  Solve[
    r1^3*(Y1^2 + K1^2) + r1^2*(2*X1*Y1 + 2*Z1*K1) + r1*(X1^2 + Z1^2 
         + P0^2*S1 + 2*P0^2*O1*S1) + P0^2*O1 == 0, 
    r1, 
    Reals
  ];
```

Let's take a look at what we have, for each one of the three solutions:

```
ContourPlot[#, {P0, 0, 2}, {del0, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All] & /@ (r1 /. F11)
```

[image: three contour plots]

It will be up to you to see which has significance to you. If you want to combine multiple plots, consider using `Show`.

Comment: Sir, where should I use 'Show' to combine all these three plots?

Comment: Have you tried `Show[ContourPlot[...]& /@ (r1 /. F11)]` as a start? You may also try to combine the three in a single `ContourPlot[Evaluate[r1 /. F11], ...]`.